# Integrating webpack and wix-stylable using custom webpack config

Tags: reactjs, webpack, gatsby

We are getting an error trying to add a wix-stylable plugin in Gatsby using the webpack custom config.

We tried following stylable guide but we can't seem to make this work. We tried to integrate the plugin in different ways but we still end up getting the same errors.

There's an issue open on github in which is possible to see the screenshots relate to our problem.

https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/14487

Thank you all

Comment: Is there *any* code that you can share?

Comment: Hi @ksav. Yest we just updated the project so you can have a look. https://github.com/azharulc/bjjfreak-frontend/tree/stylable-build

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, you can now download the a gasby stylable plugin at the following link. https://github.com/superhawk610/gatsby-plugin-stylable